# Create grids on a plane

Tags: modeling

How can I create grids on a plane in Blender? Namely, a plan object is subdivided into multiple grid objects. I tried the following but did not work:

1. Create a plane
2. Select it in object mode
3. Tab to enter edit mode
4. Subdivide in into n components. In the viewport, I observe the plane is subdivided to the specified number of grids
5. Select all sub faces, and <kbd>P</kbd> *Separate by Loose Parts*
6. back to object mode. No new grid objects are either appearing in the viewport nor the outliner

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you are trying to do. What you did is subdividing a plane into a grid. If you want a different object in addition to the plane, then add another plane object in object mode.

Comment: hello please show a screenshot and give more details because for the moment it's hard to understand what you're trying to achieve and what you have right now, if you want something that looks like a grid object, you can inset all the faces and remove them?

Answer (score 0):

in Object Mode:

[Add] > [Mesh] > [Grid]

*look :

[image: drid]

---

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to find the solution. It turned out I missed a step (edge split) prior to pressing <kbd>P</kbd> *Separate > By Loose Parts*. Naturally if don't split the edges there would not be any loose parts.

1. Create a plane
2. Select it in object mode
3. Tab to enter edit mode
4. Subdivide in into n components. In the viewport, I observe the plane is subdivided to the specified number of grids
5. In *Edge* mode, *Split Edge*. This fixed the problem
6. Select all sub faces, and <kbd>P</kbd> *Separate > By Loose Parts*

Back to object mode. No new grid objects are either appearing in the viewport nor the outliner.